# IntelliJ IDEA mac debugger not working correctly

Tags: macos, debugging, intellij-idea

The following behaviour appears **only** on the mac versions of IntelliJ IDEA. First discovered it in version 2015, but in the currently newest 2017.1 it's still the same (both community/commercial).

- set a breakpoint and start the application in debug mode (in my case a Spring Boot application started with application debug)
  --> for the first time after server start the execution stops at the breakpoint (correct)
- click "Run to cursor" and continue with the execution
- execute the same to run again into the same breakpoint
  --> the debugger does not stop anymore at the breakpoint (incorrect)

It also happens sometimes, that if the breakpoint is removed, the cursor still stops at the line, where the breakpoint was before.

After a server restart, everything goes fine again until the first execution.

Of course the code wasn`t changed in the meantime.

For these reasons, the debugger on mac is practically unusable.

Any ideas, if it's a bug (would be weird not having it fixed since years), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it happen with the latest Oracle Java build? Anything interesting in the [debugger logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125)?

Comment: I don't see any interesting in the debugger logs except, that if the wrong behaviour happens (not stopping at the breakpoint), then the log also doesn't rotate.
my java version:
java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)